# Stop CO2 laser firing through holes in glass

Tags: experimental-physics, laser

How would you prevent a CO<sub>2</sub> laser with interlocks used to mark glass  from firing if there were holes in the glass. Usually the interlocks prevent the laser from firing unless it is pressed against glass which will absorb the energy, but the laser will still fire if there are holes in the glass--how can you prevent this?